# can't connect to db through another class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have an issue that I can't figure out. I have a class Database which if I use it directly I connect to db regularly. I have another class Categories and I want to call a Database object. The problem is that if I call $db->connect in categories does not work. I tried call mysql_connect directly in Categories and it works fine!

Why can't I use `$db->connect (the error is Access denied for user 'user'@'0.0.0.0' (using password: YES)`.

My code in class Database is:

```
public function connect($new_link=false){
    $this->link_id = @mysql_connect($this->server,$this->user,$this->pass,$new_link);

    echo "<br/>link_id = ".$this->link_id;
    if (!$this->link_id){//open failed
        $this->oops("Could not connect to server: <b>$this->server</b>.");
        }
        else{
            echo "Connected to server <br/>";            
        }

    if(!@mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link_id)){//no database
        $this->oops("Could not open database: <b>$this->database</b>.");
        }
        else{
            echo "Database opened <br/>";            
        }

    // unset the data so it can't be dumped
    $this->server='';
    $this->user='';
    $this->pass='';
    $this->database='';
}#-#connect()
```

My code in class Category is:

```
public static function selectAll() { // SELECT All Function
    $db = Database::obtain();
        // connect to the server
        $db->connect();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM productCategory";
        $rows = $db->fetch_array($sql);

        return $rows;
    }
```

Database::obtain code

```
public static function obtain($server=null, $user=null, $pass=null, $database=null){
    if (!self::$instance){ 
        self::$instance = new Database($server, $user, $pass, $database); 
    } 

    return self::$instance; 
}#-#obtain()
```

Am I doing sth wrong, that I can't see?

Comment: If you unset the database connection data(server, user, ...), where is set again for other calls. Also, would you mind to out the Database::obtain code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is "Access denied for user 'user'@'0.0.0.0'"
That means when you instantiate your class with $db = Database::obtain(); You don't set the values for server, user, pass, database. Probably the class Database implements a singleton pattern, and the method obtain() just returns the instance without any properties set.

Comment: you are right about obtain(). The problem is that out of Category class database code works fine....it connects to server..

Comment: Well, it works probably because you call a method that sets the user, password, database, server. But being a singleton means that the same instance will be provided until the script finishes running and I see that you set those values to '' after connect. Now I see that you provided the code for obtain, you should have something like $db = Database::obtain($server, $user, $pass, $database);